# Imágenes responsivas bloqueadas por el tamaño inicial

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive

La imagen que estoy montando en el footer es el icono de una red social, a la cual le asigne un tamaño inicial desde CSS. Utilicé también Bootstrap 4 y la clase `img-fluid` (mientras no se asigne tamaño a la imagen, la imagen es responsiva).

¿Cómo puedo lograr un tamaño para las imágenes y que sea responsiva?
¿Es necesario insertar la imagen ya con el tamaño que deseo presentar?

```css
.img-size {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<a href="" class=""><img class="img-fluid img-size rounded-circle mx-1" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: Hola, debes aclarar un poco lo que estás buscando. ¿A qué te refieres con tener las imágenes responsivas pero añadiendo un tamaño? Si tienen un tamaño, por definición no van a ser responsivas. No se van a adaptar al tamaño de pantalla si ya tienen un tamaño especificado. ¿O lo que quieres es que tengan un tamaño específico en algunas resoluciones pero que sean responsivas en otras? Edita la pregunta para añadir más detalle. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: si, lo entiendo, a lo que hago referencia es al tamaño en que se presentan las imagenes cuando abres la pagina, ese tamaño inicial. debo poner la imagen ya con el tamaño desde el diseño? o se puede manejar de alguna forma, para que tambien se haga responsiva de acuerdo a la pantalla?

Answer (score 0):

para poder asignar un tamaño a un elemento y que sea responsivo deberías usar el % como unidad. Asígnale un porcentaje al width que se adecue al tamaño que buscas y debería bastar.